# EF 8 Linq Orderby with custom value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have a scenario where I have to order by from a table using EF8, which contains string as a value, but I have to convert it to int with some constant and then order by with the int value.

```
var orderedQueryable = _dbContext.tableName
.Where(q => (!q.IsDismissed) && (statuses.Any(s => q.Status == s)))
.OrderBy(q => StatusOrders[q.Status])
.ThenByDescending(q => q.LastUpdatedAt)
.GroupBy(q => q.id)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(q => q.LastUpdatedAt).First());

Dictionary<string, int> StatusOrders = new Dictionary<string, int> {
            {"Executing", 1},
            {"Submitted", 2},
            {"Error", 3},
            {"Completed", 4},
    };
```

I know the reason because EF cannot create Query to fetch data with the linq, It works fine if the query is executed. I believe it can be achieved by Linq.Expressions.Expression, but its confusing. Can someone help me with this.

I wrote it like below, I am sure this is not correct approach

```
var orderedQueryable = _dbContext.tableName
.Where(q => (!q.IsDismissed) && (statuses.Any(s => q.Status == s)))
.OrderBy(q => (q.Status == StatusOrders .Executing? 1: q.Status == StatusOrders .Submitted? 2 : q.Status == StatusOrders .Error ? 3 : q.Status == StatusOrders .Completed ? 4 : 0))
.ThenByDescending(q => q.LastUpdatedAt)
.GroupBy(q => q.id)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(q => q.LastUpdatedAt).First());
```

Comment: Actually you can OrderByDescending on the second char of the words to achieve the same effect

Comment: (But that set of ternary would be my suggestion)

Comment: so there is not any other options right?

Comment: Sure. What other options do you want? You could store another column in the DB for the order, for example.. I consider sorting to be the UI's problem anyway - your DB has enough to do, why ask it to sort stuff too?

Comment: I thought of creating dynamic orderby method. but anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Kaizen; go for the simple solution, not the perfect one